# When do we use := and when do we use = in GNU makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What are the scenarios , where `=` is preferred over `:=` ?
What are the scenarios, where `:=` is preferred over `=` ?
I read from [gnu](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) site, that usage of `=` makes `make` run slower. I just wonder, when do we use `=` in makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, `=` is used when you want to delay expansion of the right side until the variable is used.

This allows you to define variables in any order.  It also allows you to create variables with values that refer to automatic variables (remember automatic variables have no value until the rule is being run).  So for example:

```
my_FLAGS = -a
your_FLAGS = -b

FLAGS = $($@_FLAGS)

my your : ; @echo $(FLAGS)
```

this cannot work if you use `:=` because when the `FLAGS` variable is defined, `$@` has no value.

They are also useful when defining user-defined functions that can later be invoked with `$(call ...)`; you don't want those to be expanded until they are called.

Answer (score 1):

With simply defined variables you can do things like recursively use the variable:

```
ITEMS := one two three
ITEMS := $(addsuffix $(ITEMS))
```

This is because the simple assignment (`:=`) happens in the order you read them

Non simple assignment (`=`) is recursively expanded so if you assign it to other variables they are in turn expanded until you end up with the final result that contains all the expanded parts. Note that the makefile first parses the file so that the order you do the assignment is not so important, examples to follow:

i.e. this is not allowed:

```
ITEMS = one two three
ITEMS = $(addsuffix $(ITEMS))
```

So this affects when you want to use each type. With non simple you can do:

```
ITEMS1 = a b c
ITEMS_all = $(ITEMS1) $(ITEMS2)
ITEMS2 = d e f
```

And now ITEMS_ALL will contain `a b c d e f` - even though they are not defined in order, this can be very useful. So if you just want to assign a simply value - stick with `:=` if you want to keep adding things to a variable you  might want to use `=`...

Comment: You sure about the *"after first parsing the file"* part? If I remember correctly, the expansion happens each time you use the variable.

Comment: you are right - recursively expanded in fact :) - I will clarify that part, I was attempting to keep it trivial for the purpose of the context of the example... i'll update that part